# Unable to load pdf file in Ajax jquery call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm new to Jquery and Ajax , trying to load my pdf from local . However it is not executing , there is no error in the console.

```
 var $jq = jQuery.noConflict();

 $jq(document).ready(function() {
     $jq('#submit').click(function(event) {
         console.log("Document loaded");                        
     $jq.ajax({

          dataType: 'native',
            url: "file:////Users/vinothmac/Downloads/header.jpg",
        xhrFields: {
            responseType: 'blob'
          },
          success: function(blob){
            console.log(blob.size);
              var link=document.createElement('a');
              link.href=window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
              link.download="Dossier_" + new Date() + ".pdf";
              link.click();
          }
        });
     });
 });
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: You cannot load the files directly from your local drive. Serve this file from the server that you are using and you should be able to download it.

Comment: Can you paste your network request ?

Comment: I have added, both screen shot